# What does "Inspection 'Unresolved reference' actually mean?

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm

PyCharm. Here's the code:

```
# db_create.py
#
# Create the database and tables
#

import sqlite3
from config import DATABASE_PATH

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Create table
    cursor.execute("""
                    CREATE TABLE ftasks(
                    task_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    name TEXT NOT NULL,
                    due_date TEXT NOT NULL,
                    priority INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    status INTEGER NOT NULL)
                    """)

    # Insert dummy data into the table
    cursor.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO ftasks (name, due_date, priority, status)
                    VALUES("Finish this tutorial", "02/03/2014", 10, 1)
                    """)

    cursor.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO ftasks (name, due_date, priority, status)
                    VALUES("Finish Real Python Course 2", "02/03/2014", 10, 1)
                    """)
```

The code works just fine. The db is created and all is well.  However, I get this message on the IDE.  Not sure what it is referring to:

[image]

I got the error message to go away by simply changing this code from how it appears above:

```
# Insert dummy data into the table
cursor.execute("""
                INSERT INTO ftasks (name, due_date, priority, status)
                VALUES('Finish this tutorial', '02/03/2014', 10, 1)
                """)

cursor.execute("""
                INSERT INTO ftasks (name, due_date, priority, status)
                VALUES('Finish Real Python Course 2', '02/03/2014', 10, 1)
                """)
```

The only change is to use single quotes inside the SQL statement.

Why is the double-quoted version an unresolved reference?

I should note that both versions of the code result in **exactly** the same database file and contents.

Further research based on the suggestion that the double quotes inside the triple quotes cold be causing problems with PyCharm's editor/parser.

I tried this code on the editor:

```
a = """
INSERT INTO atable (column1, column2)
VALUES ("test",'test')
"""

b = """
BLAH BLAH atable (column1, column2)
BLAH ("test",'test')
"""
```

and also ran it on the Python command line:

```
>>> a = """
INSERT INTO atable (column1, column2)
VALUES ("test",'test')
"""
>>> b = """
BLAH BLAH atable (column1, column2)
BLAH ("test",'test')
"""
>>> a
'\nINSERT INTO atable (column1, column2)\nVALUES ("test",\'test\')\n'

>>> b
'\nBLAH BLAH atable (column1, column2)\nBLAH ("test",\'test\')\n'
```

Both of the above definitions produce strings with exactly the same structure.  I am not seeing any issues regarding the use of the two types of quotes inside a triple-quoted string either at the Python command line, on IDLE or in PyCharm.

The IDE editor only has an issue with the string SQL version of the string and not the other:

[image]

If I hover the pointer over the brown highlights I get the error message.  The "BLAH BLAH" version has no issues.

This tells me it has something to do with SQL/SQLite.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got word back from JetBrains.  It's a bug.  They are working on it.

Comment: bug number would be useful to share

Answer (score 0):

When you using double quotes inside of a string bounded by `"""`, you are asking for trouble.

Python is able to handle a double-quote in these types of situations, but it appears your editor doesn't like it - most likely your editor uses a simpler parser than the Python interpreter, and chokes on String in the format  `""" x"x """`.

"Unresolved Reference" in this context means that PyCharm thinks the word `Finish` is a reference variable, since it incorrectly believes that the double-quote ended your string. Of course you do not have a reference variable named `Finish`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tested a couple of things based on your idea and updated the question with further documentation.  I'd appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: While this answer may be right over all (that Pycharm is confused by the triple quoted strings), your FYI at the end is a bit misleading. The kind of quotes that Python uses in the `repr` of a string doesn't have anything to do with the quotes that were used by the programmer to write the string literal in any way. The current `repr` algorithm is: "if there are any single quotes in the string and no double quotes, quote with double quotes, otherwise quote with single quotes." I believe this is an implementation detail though, so you probably shouldn't rely upon it.

Comment: @martin's: Whichever quotes Python displays with `repr` has absolutely no bearing on which quotes were used in creating the string.  If you start a triple-quoted string with """ you had better finish it with """.

Comment: So you are saying that in `repr` triple quotes simply produces a change of state that reverts back once another set of triple quotes is seen by the parser?  OK.  I get that.  Still, PyCharm is not complaining about the exact same string structure if I change the SQL tokens with "BLAH".  So, it isn't really confused --at least not in this example-- by the various quote combinations --it seems-- but rather it has an issue with the quote combination when used in the context of a SQL statement.  In that context, what exactly is an unresolved reference?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the clarification. I am fairly new to Python but have been in software development for over twenty years.  Always cool to learn something new.

Comment: "Unresolved reference" would mean that PyCharm thinks the word "Finish" is a reference variable, since it believes that the double-quote ended your string.

Comment: You should be able to recreate the same error message if you attempt to read a non-existent reference name somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I guess I can see that.  I might ping JetBrain and see what they have to say.  Obviously the fact that there are SQL tokens in the string is triggering a different interpretation. Take those away and it is perfectly happy.